# How can you pass a parameter from an action to the layout in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

The global layout.php file contains the  tags for each page:

```
<body> 
    <?php echo $sf_content ?>
</body>
```

But for all my inner HTML pages of the site, a class is applied to the body tag:

```
 <body class="inner-page"> 
    <?php echo $sf_content ?>
 </body>
```

How can I pass in a class to the layout from different templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your layout.php

```
<body <?php if (!include_slot('body_id')): ?>id="default"<?php endif; ?>>
```

in your templates :

```
<?php slot('body_id') ?>id="bla"<?php end_slot(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php slot(
  'body_id',
  sprintf('id="%s"', $sf_params->get('module')))
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution I used with Symfony 1.2+

Use setSlot() in the action:

```
$this->getResponse()->setSlot('home_page', 'yes');
```

Then use get_slot() in the Layout:

```
<body class="<?php echo has_slot('home_page') ? 'home-page' : 'inner-page' ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

In most MVC frameworks, you access variables in the layout the same way you access them in the view files.

So, if you did something like $this->view->my_data=10; in the control. You can access it in the layout by:
echo $this->my_data.

This was pseudo code, adjust it to the symphony way.

Comment: The "Symfony way" is to use slots. It's considered a feature that view variables are not assigned in the layout file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 90% sure that you do this the same way you'd do it from a regular view file. So as long as you set the variable in the action, it should be accessible from the layout.php file.

In your action:

```
$this->body_class = "xxx";
```

In layout.php

```
<body class="<?php echo $body_class?>">
```

Be sure to run some checks to make sure $body_class is set.

Comment: This is what I managed to find about this: http://www.symfonydeveloper.com/2009/03/05/passing-variables-from-an-action-or-module-template-to-a-layout-template/

Answer (score 0):

sfConfig::set('name_here', $variableHere);
$variable = sfConfig::get('name_here');

I use this a lot.  Use this anywhere on the code.